# How to suspend a MIG in GCP so that I can stop a VM for cost saving

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a managed instance group with 1 VM (Autoscaling and Autohealing are not configured).  I need to stop the VM over weekends to reduce cost? How can I flexibly do that taking minial steps and securely? I do not want to erase the state (disk).

I tried options like abandon which will take instance out of MIG but cannot add it again to MIG. Any advise is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Picked this from Google docs which might help you: (Note: both have limitations)

Option 1: [Suspending a VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/suspend-resume-instance)

If you want to keep your VM instance around but do not want to be charged for it when it is not in use, you can suspend the VM. When you suspend a VM, Google preserves the VM in your project and moves the contents of the VM's memory to storage. While the VM is suspended, Google only charges for the storage used to preserve the VM's memory.

Option 2: [Using stateful MIGs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/stateful-migs):

If you want to preserve a state of a MIG (attached disks & metadata). This is recommended for DB, data processing etc.,